# Is there a way to make a SSRS report password protected?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, password-protection

I have a report set up for a department. The data is accessed on a replicated server on the backend with a fixed password.

What I normally do is add a new role for the user accessing the report as a browser, then they can see the report and work from there.

However, the machine that is being used to access a new report is logged on under a general user account and neets to remain this way, the report that is being accessed is confidential and can only be accessed by certain staff members.

I have played around with the security settings to see if windows authentication would work but i struggled.

What I was hopping to achieve was the following:
let a user access the report on the machine via a password to run the report (preferably their user log on detais even though the machine will be logged on under a different user).

If this is not possible, would it be possible to create a password protected report using parameters?

apologies If i am not clear, I am happy to explain further if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a work around.

I have added the users I wanted to have access to the Security tab.

Using powershell I have created a script to ask for credentials to open "internet explorer" as the user I want to have access.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" http://PATHTOMYREPORT -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

From here I then created a batch file that would execute this powershell script for me

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\powershellscript.ps1'"
```

I then created a shortcut to the batch file on the desktop, in the shortcut options I set it to run as minimized so the batch file output wouldnt appear, i renamed the shorcut after my report. Gave it an inconspicuos icon.

So what happens when someone double clicks the icon?

they get asked for their organisation log on details in a neat window.

[image]
when they enter their details the report should open successfully in internet explorer provided they have been added as a report browser to the security element of the report as outlined by @B.Serbele.

If a non intended user opens it, enters their details, it just crashes out.

No doubt you may find issues with this, i.e. someone can access the C drive and delete the powershell script or shortcut etc etc. 
But its the best I could do with the set up we have at the moment.

Hope it may help someone.

Comment: Nice workaround. Thanks for sharing ti with others.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is only possible to protect a report using AD credentials. This works fine, but is not useable if there are non-AD users who have to access the report.

What you can do is [generate an SSRS report as a password protected PDF](https://go.christiansteven.com/bi-blog/ssrs/how-to-generate-an-ssrs-report-as-a-password-protected-pdf) using [SQL-RD](https://go.christiansteven.com/start-sql-rd/schedule-ssrs-reports) and send it on a schedule.

Comment: thanks for the advice, unfortunately it isnt a solution for me, I greatly appreciate the response though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the access to the report itself at the report level.  In Reporting Services you navigate to the report and click the down arrow to the right of the report name.
[image]

On the next screen you make sure the Security tab is highlighted.  You can then add groups or users (Domain\User) and their roles for that report. [image] Even though this is not password protecting the report it is limiting access to only authorized individuals.

Comment: @B.Serbele, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately the user that is permanently logged onto the maching is a general user, this is a profile that is used throughout the organisation, if i add that user to the security role:browser, then any machine logged in under general user can access this confidential data. Thanks again for the input though.